# What's the chrome default for QUIC protocol?

Tags: google-chrome

Navigating to **chrome://flags/#enable-quic** in Chrome, I can see that the "experimental quic protocol" is set to default.

Having it set to enabled means it's enabled, and disabled means it's disabled, pretty straightforward.

But what's default equal to? Enabled? Disabled? Something in between?

## EDIT

If you go to **chrome://net-internals/#quic** you can see your live QUIC session.

Since I have live QUIC session, I assume they're enabled.

But is there a difference with default and enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default QUIC is enabled, but only for websites that support it,
such as Google's own websites.

[Wikipedia QUIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QUIC) says this :

> As of December 2017, 97.5% of websites using QUIC are running LiteSpeed Web Server.

If you are curious about which websites support it, the extension
[HTTP/2 and SPDY indicator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en)
adds an indicator button for HTTP/2, SPDY and QUIC support for each website.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since December 2018 the default setting seems to disable QUIC on Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) d.d. 9th January 2019.
I don't know why this has been changed without notice.